# Using YouTube Android Api to show videos

Tags: youtube-api

I have an app with list of videos from youtube and the user can choose one and play it using YoutubePlayer (of the official api). My question is : it is legal to play any video from YouTube in my app ?
Should I ask the owners of the videos for permission to play their videos in my app ?

I read the terms of service of YouTube and I did not understand that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the API, then you needn't worry about asking any permission to play others' videos. Uploaders also have a terms of service, whereby they grant access to play their videos through any official means unless they note it somewhere ... so, for example, they'd have to set videos as private, or set various parameters that forbid embedding, mobile playback, etc. If the video owner hasn't set those, then their use of the YouTube platform enables you to use the API to play them. This comes not from the API terms of service but from the general terms of service:

https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

Specifically, 6-C which states that when users upload content to YouTube, they grant YouTube a

> worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free, sublicenseable and
>   transferable license to use, reproduce, distribute, prepare derivative
>   works of, display, and perform the Content in connection with the
>   Service and YouTube's (and its successors' and affiliates') business,
>   including without limitation for promoting and redistributing part or
>   all of the Service (and derivative works thereof) in any media formats
>   and through any media channels. You also hereby grant each user of the
>   Service a non-exclusive license to access your Content through the
>   Service, and to use, reproduce, distribute, display and perform such
>   Content as permitted through the functionality of the Service and
>   under these Terms of Service.

Since YouTube, with those licenses, allows them to be accessed via the API, they are in a sense covering you with their license. Of course, if you ever implement something without the official API, or if you break the API terms of service in some other way, then you wouldn't be covered by this.